# Does the impulse response of every stable system have finite energy?

Tags: linear-systems, impulse-response, homework, stability

I need to show that the impulse response of every stable system has finite energy.
I have trouble solving this problem.
Since impulse input signal is unbounded, I can't apply BIBO stability of system well.
I'd like to know how can I approach to this problem.[image: problem image]

Comment: who says you need to use an impulse? That's the fallacy here. Try to think of an input that makes your system output its own impulse response's energy; you know that this is unbounded.

Comment: So you need to show that if $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt < \infty$$ then $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt < \infty$$ Can you do that?

Comment: @Jdip: There are functions that are in $L^1$ but not in $L^2$.

Answer (score 4):

In general, BIBO-stability doesn't imply finite energy of the impulse response. Neither does finite energy of the impulse response imply BIBO-stability.

**Example 1: BIBO-stable but infinite energy**

$$h(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}},&0<t\le 1\\0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

We have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=2\sqrt{t}\Big|_0^1=2$$

but

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t}=\ln t\Big|_0^1=\infty$$

**Example 2: finite energy but not BIBO-stable**

$$h(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{t},&t\ge 1\\0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

We have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{t}\Big|_1^{\infty}=1$$

but

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t}=\ln t\Big|_1^{\infty}=\infty$$

However, if $h(t)$ satisfies certain conditions, we can show that stability implies finite energy and vice versa.

> If $h(t)$ is bounded, i.e., if $\max_t|h(t)|<\infty$, BIBO stability implies that $h(t)$ has finite energy:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\infty\Longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt<\infty$$

**Proof:**

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|\cdot|h(t)|dt\\&\le\max_t|h(t)|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\infty
\end{align*}

if $\max_t|h(t)|<\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\infty$.

> If $h(t)$ has finite support, i.e., if $h(t)=0$ for $t\notin [a,b]$ with $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, finite energy of $h(t)$ implies BIBO stability:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt<\infty\Longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\infty$$

**Proof:**

With the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(t)||h(t)|dt\right)^2\le\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(t)|^2dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt$$

with $g(t)=1$, $t\in[a,b]$ (and $g(t)=0$ otherwise), and considering the finite support of $h(t)$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{a}^{b}|h(t)|dt\right)^2\le\int_{a}^{b}dt\int_{a}^{b}|h(t)|^2dt=(b-a)\int_{a}^{b}|h(t)|^2dt<\infty
\end{align*}

if $[a,b]$ is finite and if $\int_{a}^{b}|h(t)|^2dt<\infty$.

In sum:

- If $h(t)$ is bounded, BIBO-stability implies finite energy of $h(t)$.
- If $h(t)$ vanishes outside a finite interval, finite energy of $h(t)$ implies BIBO-stability.